# C# in Windows Form Application, how can I get the label to auto-refresh from UDP client?

Tags: c#, winforms, udp

Right now, I have button which creates an event where a decimal is read from a UDP listener (in a different class), and being converted ToString() for my label.
If I run my UDP listener in a console window, it updates in real time fine. But here, it updates the label in the first instance, and stops refreshing. I've tried calling the UDPlistener asynchronously but still unable to auto-refresh the label.

```
private void btnBopIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string firstTicker, secondTicker;
        int myCurrentPort;            

        string PortNumber = textPortNumber.Text;
        myCurrentPort = Convert.ToInt32(PortNumber);

        firstTicker = textFirstTicker.Text;
        secondTicker = textSecondTicker.Text;

//I call the UDPmethod asynchronously right here, and have the async outside the btn loop 

        CallUDPmethod(myCurrentPort, firstTicker, secondTicker);
        this.labelSpread.Refresh();
    }


    private async void CallUDPmethod(int port, string symb1, string symb2)
    {
        var result =await myUDPmethodAsync(port, symb1, symb2);
        this.labelSpread.Text = Convert.ToString(result);

//Right here^^^^^^ I want labelSpread.Text to auto update, but it only
//gives me the first instance and does not refresh

    }

    private Task<decimal> myUDPmethodAsync(int port, string symb1, string symb2)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myUDPmethod(port, symb1, symb2));
    }

    private decimal myUDPmethod(int port, string symb1, string symb2)
    {
        UDPListener myListener = new UDPListener();
        decimal result = myListener.SpreadValue(port, symb1, symb2);
        return result;
    }
```

I've also tried simply using the following code instead of the async method in the btn loop. But, it also only gives me the first instance of the decimal spread:

```
    UDPListener myListener = new UDPListener();
    decimal spread = myListener.SpreadValue(myCurrentPort, firstTicker, secondTicker);
    labelSpread.Text = Convert.ToString(spread);
```

Comment: but what's the problem? if you press the button your code only waits for one value, so each time you press the button you should get a new value, is not that what you need?

Comment: Hey Gusman, I'm just wondering if it's possible for the label to autoupdate without me needing to press anything.

Comment: so you mean you whant a loop?

Comment: I think the problem is that 'myUDPmethod' returns a decimal. What I really want is myUDPmethod to be void so that it continuously updates the value.

Comment: No, that's no problem, first, on myUDPmethod remember to destroy the listener, and on your CallUDPmethod just surround it with `while(true){ /*...*/ }`, that's a dirty way of doing it but you get the concept.